# Issues with linking to certain functions in my own shared library on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have created a shared library(.so) in Linux, i am facing a very weird issue.
Initially i have added 3 functions(write_myown,setfolder,register) in library, then i added a few more(init,write_re).

Basically the entire library is implemented in C++, however the APIs need to be called from both C and C++ based executables. Hence i have used extern "C" for the APIs.

The strange issue i am facing is that when i try to use the functions 
write_myown, setfolder and register, the linking goes thru and executable is created.

But when i try to call functions init or write_re the linking fails, with undefined reference error.

Even stranger thing that i think but not sure about is that i guess when i am building C only programs it works fine, but when i am building C++ based code, this issue is seen.

I have already checked and confirmed the following things

1. The library (.so ) is existing in /usr/lib ( I put it there )
2. ldconfig -p | grep mylibname shows that my library is present.
3. When i dont call init or write_re the executable is generated, and objdump/readelf shows the appropriate references.
4. ldd on mylibrary.so shows both init and write_re also exist, visibility is global.
5. The executables or .0 created show the right dependency to mylibrary.
6. There are no versions of mylibrary.
7. I have confirmed that it is referencing the right .so.
8. nm on my library show that all the functions exist.

Any idea how i can solve this? And what could be the issue.
If not how i can proceed with investigation.
Please let me know if any further details are required.

Best Regards,
Pavan

Comment: `write` is a function already inside `libc.so.6` and `register` is a keyword. You should use different names...

Comment: If giving a C interface, it is usual to have all your symbols sharing a common prefix.... so rename all your functions so that tkeir name starts with e.g. `pavan_`

Comment: Hi Basile, thanks for your response, sorry for the confusion, i am not using any standard functions names.

Comment: `write` *is* a standard name in `libc`; if you are not using that name, edit your question to give the actual names you are using.... And having a common prefix for your functions is still a good advice...

Comment: Edited as soon as i figured it out. Sorry once again.

Comment: Please supply a minimal example that shows this behaviour. In this case it's important to remember that C++ uses name mangling and that the `extern "C"` declaration in your .h files is visible to the C++ compiler. Most times this is the problem when mixing C and C++ and getting the behaviour you get.

Answer (score 0):

> The strange issue i am facing is that when i try to use the functions write_myown, setfolder and register, the linking goes thru and executable is created.
>
> But when i try to call functions init or write_re the linking fails, with undefined reference error.

My crystall ball says: when you wrote prototypes for `write_myown` and `setfolder` in your `.h` file, you've added `extern "C"` to them.

But when you later added `write_re`, you put `extern "C"` on their definition in the `.cc` file, but neglected to add it to their prototypes in `.h`.

If so,

- the functions are *defined* with their non-mangled form in the library, and
- a pure `C` executable can use them fine, and
- a `C++` object that references them (outside of the library) does *not* see `extern "C"` on them, and so wants their *mangled* form (which is of course *not* provided by the library).

This hypothesis I think fits all the facts currently in your question, and is trivial to verify: did the error message from the linker say `undefined symbol: write_re`, or did it say `undefined symbol: write_re(some, parameter, types)` ?

If the latter, that's a dead giveaway that some object is referencing *mangled* name.